# DOM xml parsing from file res/xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, dom

I looking for solution to parse xml file from res/xml folder with DOM (to read, modify xml).
The method

```
         getResources().getXml(id)
```

just return XmlResourceParser object, how can I convert it into Document to parse?
I also followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329308/open-xml-file-from-res-xml-in-android/4329390#4329390) but it does not help.

How can I solve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: SAX is best for Parsing XML i think.

Comment: Do note: if you read a file from the `res/xml` folder and get a Document you can't save any changes you make back to the original file in the `res/xml` folder.

Comment: @PareshMayani I also want to edit xml so SAX is not enough.

Comment: @Femi I just want to work on memory, so I do not need save this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the xml file in the `res/raw` folder, and then you can use `getResources().getRawResource(R.raw.resource_id)` to get an `InputStream` which you can process using all the standard DOM methods (wrap it in an `InputSource`, etc).

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. But I don't understand how difference between res/raw and res/xml. Can you explain this? Why can't I use res/xml?

Comment: XML files in `res/xml` are parsed at compile time and stored in the apk in a structure that can be retrieved using `getResources().getXml`, but the raw data isn't made available. All files in `res/raw` are stored in the apk in a form that can be retrieved as an InputStream with `getRawResource`. You can read more on this in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this link which is below

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Resources/XML

this is the simple demo of dom parcer which is call xml file from locally.so you can try 
also from webservices..try and make sure you get your data