# How to parse XML from R.xml folder?

Tags: android

While doing this I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/). It parses XML well, but from URL. I need to change XML source to R.xml folder.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element`
```

How to change `String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);` line of code so that XML will be taken from R.xml folder?

Comment: you should read the content of the file, what`s the issue?

Comment: Do you want to parse a file on the storage card, or from your own resources?

Comment: XML should be taken from R.xml folder not from URL

Comment: Have You tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329308/open-xml-file-from-res-xml-in-android ?

Comment: @Steelight. Yes, I want to parse a file from my own resources(R.xml)

Comment: `InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourxml);`

Comment: The tutorial you are following reads from http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml. So u need to change that in ur url

Comment: @rahulserver point is here not to change url, change URL to R.xml

Comment: @blackbelt then how to convert xml from inputstream to string

Comment: @JoeRichard do a little effort and look for "read inputstream in a String" on goolge

Comment: Why not place your XML file in your res/xml folder? Then you can use getRessources().getXml(R.xml.YOURFILE) which directly returns an XML parser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your xml file is in res/xml please see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html. Another option would be to place your file in the asset folder, then you can access it like described here [How to get URI from an asset File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file).

It's not clear from your question what exactly your problem is. If none of the above options is for you please specify your requirements a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a folder /res/xml, and our own XML file myxml.xml.

Then you can open it using:

```
Resources res = activity.getResources();
XmlResourceParser xrp = res.getXml(R.xml.your_resId);
```

You can follow [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html) post.